# Finding the equation of the plane

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Passing through the points $(1,1,0)$, $(2,0,2)$, and $(0,3,3)$.

How do I know which components to subtract with which other component, in what order, to get it in ijk-form?

I know that the cross product of the two vectors will give me the normal vector. And from there I know how to get the equation of the plane.

\begin{align}&((2-1)i - (0-1)j + (2+0)k) \times ((0-1)i + (3-1)j + (3-0)k
\\&= (2i-j+2k) \times (-i+2j+3k) \end{align}

It's supposed to be $(2i-j+2k) \times (i-2j-3k)$

I'm just having troubles knowing which components to subtract.

Comment: Math symbols should be placed between dollar signs. For example `i x j` is rendered as "i x j", but if you place dollars `$i \times j$` then it becomes $i\times j$. Learn more about it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to solve the problem:

A plane (not passing through the origin) can be described by
$$ax+by+cz = 1.$$
Use the three points to compute $a$, $b$, and $c$. Your final answer should be $$7x + 5y -z = 12.$$

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to get the normal direction, it doesn't matter.

Different options of ordering will still give you the normal direction, they just differ by a scalar multiple.

After you get the normal direction, you still have to solve for the constant by substituing one of the point.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As a shortcut way, the equation of a plane passes through three points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, and $(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ is the determinant
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1 \\
 x_1-x_2 & y_1-y_2 & z_1-z_2 \\
 x_2-x_3 & y_2-y_3 & z_2-z_3 \\
\end{array}
\right|=0
$$